# Reference type arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

I'm trying to store the same data in two different arrays: one is a 2D array of "spots", the other is a array of objects that also holds an array of "spots".

The arrays are indexed differently, but I can change info in one array, and it will change in the other as well. I was under the impression that arrays hold reference types, so because the second array (`tileData`) was made from the first array (`gameBoardData`), when I change the array within the tile, why doesn't it change the data in the gameBoardData? isn't the tile made from references to the `gameBoardData`? if not, how do I do what I'm describing?

```
    public Spot[,] gameBoardData { get; private set; }
    public Tile[] tileData { get; private set; }

    private void initializeBoard()
    {
        this.gameBoardData = new Spot[4, 4];

        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
            {
                this.gameBoardData[row, column] = new Spot();
                this.gameBoardData[row, column].pieceState = 0;
            }
        }

        Tile tile1 = new Tile( new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[0, 0], gameBoardData[0, 1], gameBoardData[1, 1], gameBoardData[1, 0] });
        Tile tile2 = new Tile(new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[0, 2], gameBoardData[0, 3], gameBoardData[1, 3], gameBoardData[2, 2] });
        Tile tile3 = new Tile(new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[2, 0], gameBoardData[2, 1], gameBoardData[3, 1], gameBoardData[3, 0] });
        Tile tile4 = new Tile(new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[2, 2], gameBoardData[2, 3], gameBoardData[3, 3], gameBoardData[3, 2] });
        this.tileData = new Tile[4] { tile1, tile2, tile3, tile4 };

    }
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but doesn't "I can change info in one array, and it will change in the other as well" contradict "when I change the array within the tile, why doesn't it change the data in the gameBoardData?" ?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I am struggling with that too.

Comment: Also, are Spot and Tile classes or structs?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why the changes are not reflected for you. Below is a sample Console App, where the changes are reflected.

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var board = new Board();
            board.InitializeBoard();
        }      
    }

    public class Board
    {
        public Spot[,] gameBoardData { get; private set; }
        public Tile[] tileData { get; private set; }

        public void InitializeBoard()
        {
            this.gameBoardData = new Spot[4, 4];

            for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
                {
                    this.gameBoardData[row, column] = new Spot();
                    this.gameBoardData[row, column].PieceState = 0;
                }
            }

            Tile tile1 = new Tile(new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[0, 0], gameBoardData[0, 1], gameBoardData[1, 1], gameBoardData[1, 0] });
            Tile tile2 = new Tile(new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[0, 2], gameBoardData[0, 3], gameBoardData[1, 3], gameBoardData[2, 2] });
            Tile tile3 = new Tile(new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[2, 0], gameBoardData[2, 1], gameBoardData[3, 1], gameBoardData[3, 0] });
            Tile tile4 = new Tile(new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[2, 2], gameBoardData[2, 3], gameBoardData[3, 3], gameBoardData[3, 2] });
            this.tileData = new Tile[4] { tile1, tile2, tile3, tile4 };


            tileData[0].Spots[0].PieceState = 25;
            if (gameBoardData[0, 0].PieceState == 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Changes Reflected");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Spot
    {
        public int PieceState { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tile
    {
        public Spot[] Spots;
        public Tile(Spot[] spots)
        {
            Spots = spots;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the 'new' keyword you used in

```
new Tile( new Spot[4] { gameBoardData[0, 0], gameBoardData[0, 1], gameBoardData[1, 1], gameBoardData[1, 0] });
```

With this, you essentially create a new Tile object with gameBoardData's data. Since it's a new object, it holds no reference to the original one.

What you want to do is:

```
var gameBoardData_1 = new Spot[4, 4];

var tile1 = new Tile(gameBoardData_1);
```

and inside you just add it to whatever container you're using
eg.:

```
m_BoardList.Add(gameBoardData_1);
```

Comment: Not really. The contents of the array are still being formed with the original objects